# snap remove says vscode is not installed

Tags: linux, haskell-snap-framework, manjaro

i want do remove vscode (because vscode will not start. no error message).

i found it in snap list, but it will not remove:

```
$ snap list | grep code
code                     8795a988         20    stable    vscode*           classic
$ snap remove vscode
snap "vscode" is not installed
$ snap remove vscode*
snap "vscode*" is not installed
```

i read the tutorial here: https://www.howtogeek.com/252047/how-to-install-and-manage-snap-packages-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts/

i got vscode from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy fix.

I'm 99% sure that snap lists Visual Studio Code as just code. Try using snap remove code.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: yes something is removed: `$ snap remove vscode
snap "vscode" is not installed`

Comment: here its called just code : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: now empty avatar for `Visual Studio Code` in program starter menu. and installed `Code - OSS` version. both visible in that screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/acfe05Q.png

Comment: `sudo snap remove code` removes the VSCode that has been installed via snap.

Answer (score 4):

It's Not VSCode in snap. It's just 'code'
So, the command is -

```
sudo snap remove code
```

Comment: why is sudo necessary?

Comment: You need administrator permissions generally to install and remove programs. Atleast for snap you need it.

Comment: I'm the only user on my machine and I don't need to prefix with sudo. I just get a password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

"snap remove code" works perfectly. I used it once.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58977013/2227743).

Comment: Works and works good under `Ubuntu 22`.